# Getting the maximum number of words in a sentence of a paragraph Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the maximum numbers of words inside a sentence of a paragraph but just can't see it.

Here is what I tried:

```
S = input("Enter a paragraph")

def getMaxNum(S):
    if "." in S:
        new_list = S.split(".")[0]
        return len(new_list)
    else "?" in S:
        new_list = S.split("?")[0]
        return len(new_list)
    else "!" in S:
        new_list = S.split("?")[0]
        return len(new_list)

getMaxNum(S)
```

In the else statement I could be getting the previous sentence values but that's not what I need to get. Any ideas how can I accomplish that?

Comment: You code looks like it is finding the first sentence and trying to return the length. It's not clear what `maximum` your question is about. Also, you are calling the result of split  `new_list` which is confusing if `S` is a string. Also confusing is that python normally finds the length of things by passing them to `len()` rather than a `.len()` method. In short, its hard to understand what you are asking. Maybe an example with input/expected-output would help.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll edit my question. There's a lot of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain of what your requirements are, but if I borrow Buoy Rina's input, here's a solution using regular expressions (pattern search strings):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
text = "I will go school tomorrow. I eat apples. Here is a six word sentence."

max_words = 0 
sentences = re.split("[.!?]", text)
for sentence in sentences:
 max_words = max( len( sentence.split() ), max_words ) 


print(f"max_words: {max_words}")
```

The `re.split()` breaks the text (or paragraph) into sentences based on "some" end of sentence punctuation.  There are likely conditions under which searching for period '.' won't yield a complete sentence, but we'll ignore that for simplicity.

The string function `split()` then breaks up the  sentence into words based on white space (the default of `split()`).  We then get the length of the resultant list to find the word count.

Answer (score -1):

```
text = "I will go school tomorrow. I eat apples. I will have a very long sentence. "

def getmaxwordcount(text):
    count_word = 0
    is_start_word = False
    counts = []
    for c in text:
        if c == ' ':
            if is_start_word:
                count_word += 1
                is_start_word = False
        elif c == '!' or c == '.' or c == '?':
            if is_start_word:
                count_word += 1
                is_start_word = False
                counts.append(count_word)
                count_word = 0
        else:
            if c.isalpha():
                if is_start_word == False:
                    is_start_word = True
    return max(counts)
getmaxwordcount(text) # 7
```

Comment: This returns 8 for the given text because you count all the words in the paragraph rather than finding the longest sentence in terms of word count.

Comment: I noticed the question was recently modified.

Answer (score -1):

- code

```py
import re

paragraph = "Two words. Three other words? Finally four another words!"

all_lengths_in_paragraph = [f"Length of {n+1}th sentence is {len(list(filter(None, x.split(' '))))}" for n, x in enumerate(list(filter(None, re.split('\.|!|\?', paragraph))))]

max_length = max([len(list(filter(None, x.split(' ')))) for x in list(filter(None, re.split('\.|!|\?', paragraph)))])

for one_length in all_lengths_in_paragraph:
  print(r)

print('maximum length is', max_length)
```

- output

```
Length of 1th sentence is 2
Length of 2th sentence is 3
Length of 3th sentence is 4
maximum length is 4
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
text = "I will go school tomorrow. I eat apples."

def foo(txt):
    max_count=0
    for i in re.split('[!.?]',txt):
        if len(i.split()) > max_count:
            max_count = len(i.split())
    return max_count

print(foo(text)) # returns 5
```